# Pointer to 1D array in constant size 2D array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a 2-dimensional integer array of constant size which I declare as

`int array[SIZE_1][SIZE_2];`

I would like to declare a pointer `p` so that I can assign a "row" of the 2-dimensional array to it, i.e.

`p = array[index];`

I have tried declaring `p` as

`int (* p)[SIZE_2];`

but this gives me a `"assignment from incompatible pointer type"` warning (GCC on MinGW).

So how do I declare `p` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are pointing to an array of integers(Row):-

```
 int *p = array[index];
 so,
 p[1] == array[index][1];
```

This also works:-

```
int array[SIZE_1][SIZE_2];
int (*p)[SIZE_2] = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a **pointer to an array of a specific size**, you could use sth. like this:

```
....
typedef int AOFSIZE[SIZE_2];      // one row

int Array[SIZE_1][SIZE_2];        // our array
int rowindex = 1;                 // any row available
AOFSIZE *ptr = &Array[rowindex];
...
```

but this is to be barely used only under some circumstances.

Regards,

rbo